# Un-defined variable error

Tags: php

Since, I am new to PHP and couldn't resolve undefined variable error in this code..
The error is: `Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\shopping\products.php`

Code:

```
    <?php
        $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        **<td><img src="<?=$row['picture']?>" /></td>**
        <td>    **<b><?=$row['name']?></b><br />**
                **<?=$row['description']?><br />**
                Price:<big style="color:green">
                    **$<?=$row['price']?></big><br /><br />**
                **<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['serial']?>)" />**
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you identify which line the error is occurring on?

Comment: Try using var_dump($row) instead of the html output and post the output

Comment: phpMyAdmin and MySQL are two different things!

Comment: without the line number it's not clear what/where the error is. Read the error message and look at the line of code that it comes from.

Comment: I am getting errors on line 6,7,8,10,11.. Infact all the lines where <?=$row[]?> tag is used..Please help me out. Thank yew..!!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your query isn't returning anything. Try adding this and looking at the output.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($row);
die;
```

If the $row is null then it wont work as an array like you have specified.

Comment: I am getting errors on line 6,7,8,10,11.. In fact all the lines where <?=$row[]?> tag is used..Please help me out. Thank yew..!!